# Is it possible to provide a username/password for authentication with the WMQTT java implementation?

Tags: java, authentication, passwords, mqtt

I am currently using IBM's java implementation of WMQTT ([found here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24006006)) to connect to a broker on my server, and I am able to connect my application successfully. However, I have not been able to figure out how to supply a username/password for authentication.

The `MqttClient` and `IMqttClient` classes don't seem to take a password argument, and I have looked through the source for `wmqtt.jar`, and still can't find anything that expects a password.

Is it possible to connect with a username/password using WMQTT? I keep finding documentation that it is, but no reference on how to do it in practice using the java implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the situation is that MQTT v3.1 (published 2010) added username/pw auth to the connect() method, but you're using IA92 which predated that, and the Java client there doesn't offer that capability.

You may want to see whether the alternative non-IBM Java client MeQanTT works with auth - https://github.com/AlbinTheander/MeQanTT (I've not checked)

I'll definitely ask folks internally to check whether there are plans to release an MQTT 3.1-compatible Java client - I know that WebSphere MQ Telemetry (commercial product from IBM) does provide that but I don't believe the IA92 SupportPac has been updated to that level right now. Watch This Space!

Comment: Okay, thanks! I looked into MeQanTT, but unfortunately it doesn't provide some of the features I would want, I'll just keep an eye out here.

Comment: you might want to check out https://github.com/fusesource/mqtt-client which was published since I left the original answer... and there's also Eclipse Paho, which is a project from IBM and Eurotech due to contain open source MQTT clients in Java and C very shortly (that will be the same code that IBM currently ships commercially)

Comment: Thanks - I'll probably use the implementation you linked to on Github, but I'll be looking forward to seeing the implementations in Eclipse Paho. Thanks for keeping up with my question